# Dropzone постит дважды (multer + dropzone)

Tags: node.js, express, multer, dropzone

После сабмита "из" dropzone получаю два пост запроса. Первый с undefined вместо файла, второй с файлом, но редирект во втором случае не работает.

```
<form id="adder" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/result/" method="post">
    <input id="img" name="file" type="file" accept="image/*">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement("#adder");

    Dropzone.options.adder = {
        paramName: "file",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        maxFilesize: 5
    };

    $("#submit-button").on("click", function (e) {
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    })
});
```

И код роутера

```
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), async (req, res, _next) => {
    console.log(file);
    res.redirect(`/?file=${file}`);
}
```

Выводит:

```
> undefined
> {
  fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: '2421474.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: 'images/',
  filename: '981201c866febc697b3c7ac1fa685895',
  path: 'images\\981201c866febc697b3c7ac1fa685895',
  size: 22006
}
```

И редиректит на `/?file=undefined`

Пробовал проверять req.file на undefined

```
if (typeof (req.file) !== "undefined") {
    var file = req.file;
    console.log(file);

    res.redirect(`/?file=${file}`);
}
```

Тогда просто не редиректит, а уходит в "вечную загрузку", после чего выдает ошибку "Не удается получить доступ к сайту" на url `/result/`

Пробовал "остановливать передачу события", тогда просто не редиректит.

Comment: вам нужно __1)__ приостановить передачу события на форму, `e.preventDefault();` __2)__ не делать бесполезный редирект в ответ на `POST` запрос, а послать данные загруженного файла, которые отработать в Dropzone

Comment: Забыл написать об этом, если приостановить передачу события, то все равно не редиректит

Comment: приостановка превратит два запроса в один, а если не превратит - навесьте что-нибудь на форму, чтобы не сабмитилась. если этот Dropzone загружает файл ajax-запросом, тогда редирект в ответ на ajax - бессмысленен, отправьте данные файла и на client-side загрузите "новую" страницу `window.location.href...`

Comment: Напишите в ответ, закрою вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема с двумя запросами к серверу решается отключением сабмита формы, например, приостановкой передачи события `submit` и/или `click`.

```
e.preventDefault();
```

А переадресация не выполняется так как сама загрузка файла происходит с помощью `ajax`. Замените вызов `res.redirect` на `res.json(file)`, а в обработчике `Dropzone` словите информацию о файле и загрузите страницу с нужным адресом, примерно так `window.location.href = '/?file=${file.filename}'`